# Lint to prevent modifying image files

Tags: html, web, eslint, lint

Goal: Prevent replacing (modifying according to git) image files.

E.g. if you have logo.jpg, you can't just overwrite it with a new logo.jpg, you have to call the new file logo2.jpg and delete the original logo.jpg.

Why: I work on a shared github repo for a website and sometimes we have to replace images. If we replace an image with a new one of the same name, then due to our cache, users would still see the old file for quite a long time. So it's important to have new file names to bust the cache.

Comment: use a git commit hook

Comment: your server should include a cache hash for serving the file. its not the job for git/lint

Comment: Alexander: Thank you for the reply/help! Would you be able to provide a bit more info on how I would implement a git commit hook with this rule?

Comment: Sysix: Thank you! I think you're right that a server cache hash would be the best solution, but unfortunately that is out of my control.

Comment: @AnonEMouse i will try to provide a full solution tomorrow

Comment: Just following up. Thank you @AlexanderNenashev.

Comment: @AnonEMouse sorry, catching up

Comment: Hi, just following up to see if you could direct me to figuring out an answer here. Thank you!